# Designing a GUI for an MS Access database

Tags: user-interface, ms-access, switch-statement

I am pretty new to MS Access databases. I have created a database and I have also meddled with basic forms. But then I came across this site http://www.databasedev.co.uk/user_interface_designs.html. It shows MS Access GUIs with a high level of customization. Can anyone guide me on how to get such a customized interface?

I need to have a login screen wherein user enters his name and password. Based on this, I have a user table where in the rights for each user are stored. Based on the value returned from the table, I need to display a swtichboard interface with the reports assigned for the particular user.

If anyone can shed some light on how to proceed with this, it would be most helpful.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: SO is used to troubleshoot specific programming items. Your question is just too broad. All UI examples from the link are using available form controls (command buttons, comboboxes, listboxes, labels, images, sub forms, and more) in various arrangements and functionality. Simply play around with them or read on various tutorials.

Comment: Hi @Manus. Your question is a little too broad for this type of site. See some info on asking questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking With regards to your question, there's lots of information and video tutorials describing the things you're after, so perhaps have a look at those first. If you come across a problem with them, you will then at least have a _specific_ problem and an example to post, which is much more what this site can help with.